# Is it Reul or Deul?

Tags: word-study, numbers, word-choice

In Numbers 1:14 (NASB)

> Of Gad; Eliasaph the son of **Deuel**.

In KJV

> of Gad, Eliasaph the son of **Deuel**;

Then, in Numbers 2:14 (NASB)

> Then follows the tribe of Gad; and the leader of the sons of Gad: Eliasaph the son of **Deuel**,

In KJV

> Then the tribe of Gad: and the captain of the sons of Gad shall be Eliasaph the son of **Reuel**.

In chapter 2, should it be Reul or Deul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why was **רְעוּאֵֽל Reuel** changed to **דְּעוּאֵֽל Deuel** in Numbers?

- The Hebrew name **רְעוּאֵֽל Reuel** is declared in Numbers / Bamidbar 2:14 but this title was changed by Masoretic scribes to **דְּעוּאֵֽל Deuel** in Numbers / Bamidbar 10:20 [MT].

**Numbers 2:14** [MT]
“And the tribe of Gad. Chieftain of the Gadites: Eliasaph son of **Reuel**.” ( וּמַטֵּ֖ה גָּ֑ד וְנָשִׂיא֙ לִבְנֵ֣י גָ֔ד אֶלְיָסָ֖ף בֶּן־רְעוּאֵֽל )

**Numbers 10:20** [MT]
“and in command of the tribal troop of Gad, Eliasaph son of **Deuel**.” ( וְעַל־צְבָ֖א מַטֵּ֣ה בְנֵי־גָ֑ד אֶלְיָסָ֖ף בֶּן־דְּעוּאֵֽל )

- We know Reuel רְעוּאֵֽל begins with the rounded letter רְ Reish, not the bent letter ד Dalet. - **However, Chizkuni notes : אליסף בן רעואל, “Elyasaf son of R’uel. Everywhere else this name appears it was spelled with the letter ד instead of with the letter ר.** [ https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.2.14?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en&p3=texts&lang3=bi ]

**Did Masoretic scribes intentionally change Reuel to Deuel in the book of Numbers?**

> ונשיא לבני גד אליסף בן רעואל, “and the prince of the sons of Gad, Elyassaph son of Re-uel.” In this instance Elyassaph’s father’s name begins with the letter ר instead of the letter ד as we have read it elsewhere. According to the Massoretes there is only one other person whose name רעואל appears with the alternate spelling דעואל.

> At any rate the switch in letters indicates that the persons concerned were anxious to obtain nearness to G’d, understanding of Him and intimacy with Him. [When spelled רעו-אל, the first three letters allude to רועה, shepherd, someone extremely caring; when spelled דעו-אל the first three letters refer to דעה intimate knowledge, intimacy. Ed.]

[ https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.2.14?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en&p3=texts&lang3=bi ]

> אליסף בן רעואל. Nachmanides writes that it is an accepted practice in the Holy Tongue to sometimes change the name of the father of the person concerning whom the Torah reveals some important fact.

> He was known by both names, each complimentary in its way. Hence the Torah mentioned both names. The former name reflects דעואל,s intellectual attachment to Hashem, the latter his emotional attachment to Hashem, Whom he viewed as his shepherd.

[ https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.2.14?lang=bi&with=Tur%20HaAroch&lang2=en&p3=texts&lang3=bi ]

Answer (score 1):

- In Num 1:14, the operative word is דְּעוּאֵֽל = "Deuel".  Paradoxically, the LXX has Ῥαγουήλ = "Ragouel".
- In Num 2:14 we have רְעוּאֵֽל = "Reuel".  In the LXX we have Ῥαγουήλ = "Ragouel".

It is possible that the LXX used a different text.  However, it is also possible we have simple copyist's error as the Hebrew "R" and "D" are a very similar shape.  The Pulpit commentary arrives at a similar conclusion:

> Verse 14. - Reuel. Probably an error of transcription for Deuel, which
> actually appears here in many MSS. The Septuagint, however, has Raguel
> (see Numbers 1:14; Numbers 7:42, etc.). The error is utterly
> unimportant, except as proving the possibility of errors in the sacred
> text. Numbers 2:14

Comment: Jesus said it was easier for heaven and earth to pass away than for that conclusion to be true.

Comment: @user21676 - I do not understand what point you are making.  Please explain.

Comment: One example, Chayyim puts 'Hadar' for one of Ishmael's sons in Genesis(vs Leningrad's 'Hadad'), and yet 'Hadad' in 1 Chronicles for the same person;  accepting this text then doesn't mean he thought it an error, since his action was clearly deliberate. Or with the Riphath/Diphath verse where they all agree; doesn't make it an error.